# how to get rollup summary of sum for all activity records in case object

Tags: trigger, visual-workflow, tasks, roll-up-summary, activity

i have an requirement.i am trying to have a rollup summary field on case object to get the total hours from all activity records. When you go to a case record and then go to the related section and then go to the activities. There you can create as many as activity records. In each records there are "start" and "end" time has to be mentioned. Based upon that the actual time in hour we will get. So we created a field on task(Field name is Time_difference_in_hours__c) which is a formula field with text type which will give us the hour for each activity record. Till now its fine.

Now i want to show the sum of all activity hour in our case record.

As task is not in master detail relationship with case,i have not got the declarative way of directly fetching roll up summary.

So i tried to achieve by flow. For that i created one number field in Case where the value will be displayed(Field name is Total_Activity_Hours__c). Here i am getting the error.   Here can use scheduled trigger flow. Also i tried using auto launched plus record trigger too. i query on all activities and try to loop them and after that when i try to assign,then i am not able to find the required hour field to make the sum.

Please help in any way.

Either by trigger or by flow.Or anything.

Answer (score 0):

I'd have a look at the [Declarative Lookup Rollup Summaries](https://sfdo-community.github.io/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries/) open source project which will be able to achieve what you're asking for in your question.

There's actually an [example](https://sfdo-community.github.io/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries/Cookbook/Files,-Activities.html) in the documentation for a count of Activities that you could modify to do a SUM (on your Formula field) rather than a COUNT operation.

Comment: here for relationship field,,,,,,,,,,,,what i should use